# How to fix an image to the bottom right with resizing window?

Tags: html, css, image

Hello I'm trying to fix an image to the very bottom right of the page and it shows fine using css:

```
.logo img{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

but when resizing the window size, the image goes on top of the content, how to fix that please?

Comment: What do you want the image to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

then use float:right on the image

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative 'z-index' on the image in your CSS, like `z-index: -1;`

This will pull the image underneath the content.

See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/WzwA5/2/